Path connectedness of the set where two smooth vector fields are parallel
Let $F=(F_1,F_2)$ and $G=(G_1, G_2)$ be two smooth vector fields. Suppose $|F(0)|\neq 0$, and either $|G(0)|\neq 0$ or at least $|G|>0$ on a punctured neighborhood of the origin.  Now consider the function
$$\alpha(X)=F_1G_2-F_2G_1$$
and suppose $\alpha(0)=0$. Also assume that $F_1, F_2, G_1, G_2$ all have isolated zeroes near the origin. I wonder if the set of zeros of $\alpha$ is locally path connected near the origin (note that the zeros of $\alpha$ are the points where the two vector fields are parallel).
I understand that the set of zeros of smooth functions can be pretty much any closed set, but I wonder if the additional information can give us more.

See here that $$f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ (with $f(0)=0$ additionally defined) is smooth everywhere and vanishes infinitely many times in any neighbourhood of $0$. Now set
$$F=(1,0),\quad G=(1,f(y))$$
Now $F$ and $G$ vanish nowhere, but $G=F$ at infinitely many discrete points in any neighbourhood of zero. Thus $\alpha(0)=0$ but there is no neighbourhood of zero where the set $\{\alpha=0\}$ is path-connected.
A valid complaint would be that $G_2=f(y)$ does not have an isolated zero at the origin - we can remedy this by setting
$$F=(1,1),\quad G=(1,1+f(y))$$
to the same effect, but now none of $F_1,F_2,G_1,G_2$ have zeros near the origin. So sadly imposing this condition does not help quash poorly-behaved cases. Note that, as mentioned in the linked question, requiring the components of $F,G$ to be analytic excludes cases such as these, but I'm not sure if it removes all possible cases.
